# To read sub directories creation date

Tags: java

I have a main folder "G:\TestFiles". Inside TestFiles folder, I have 5 sub folders created on different dates. I want to get the creation date of those sub directories. This is what I have done so far:

```
public static void main(String aa[]) throws IOException
{
        BasicFileAttributes bfa = null;

        File dir = new File("G:\\TestFiles");
        Path filePath = dir.toPath();

        File[] subDirs = dir.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File pathname) {
                return pathname.isDirectory();
            }
        });
        for (File subDir : subDirs)
        {

        bfa = Files.readAttributes(filePath, BasicFileAttributes.class);

        long milliseconds = bfa.creationTime().to(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        if((milliseconds > Long.MIN_VALUE) && (milliseconds < Long.MAX_VALUE))
        {
            Date creationDate = new Date(bfa.creationTime().to(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));

            System.out.println("File " + filePath.toString() + " created " +
                    creationDate.getDate() + "/" +
                    (creationDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" +
                    (creationDate.getYear() + 1900));
        }
        }
}
```

My output:

```
File G:\TestFiles created 7/7/2015
File G:\TestFiles created 7/7/2015
File G:\TestFiles created 7/7/2015
File G:\TestFiles created 7/7/2015
File G:\TestFiles created 7/7/2015
```

With my approach, I am not getting the correct output. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 3):

You always read the attribute of the parent folder:

```
bfa = Files.readAttributes(filePath, BasicFileAttributes.class);
```

You should read the attributes of your current subfolder

```
bfa = Files.readAttributes(subDir.toPath(), BasicFileAttributes.class);
```